# How long does google image proxy store cached images before requesting again from the original source?

Tags: facebook, email, caching, gmail, broken-image

How long does google image proxy store cached images before requesting again from the original source in gmail? Does the change in the image of original source affect the image cache and are the images in the emails replaced? If then how long does it take to make change?

I viewed old facebook email notifications and all the images are broken because the "original image url" from facebook has url signature expired.